# Auto close div after n seconds or on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I've got an MVC app that uses a DevExpress gridview for displaying data.  The reason I mention this is because after updating a record, I am trying to display a `<div>` with a message in it and have it either close (hide) after 3 seconds, or close when the user either clicks on it, or clicks on anything else on the page.  I've read a ton of articles on SO about how to close and open elements with jQuery or Javascript but I am having difficulty with it.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/fzyXJ/), which gets me about 3/4 the way there....the div opens when the button is clicked (simulates the 'Update' part of the DevExpress grid), and if you click on the message, it closes.  What I can't figure out is how to make it auto-close after 3 seconds.  I did try to use the `.delay()`, like so `$('#msg').delay(3000).toggle(500);` but it appears that `.delay()` actually stops all other UI events until the duration is over.  The side effects to this is that if the user clicks on any other part of the document, it doesn't respond until the delay duration is over....so the delay duration closes the div but then the 'click' event of the document fires and displays the div (hope that makes sense).

In short, I'm trying to auto-display a div on a postback (button click) and then either auto-close it after 3 seconds, or close it when the user clicks on it, or any other element in the document.

Any advice/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a timer with setTimeout()

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".messageInTab").click(function () {
        $(this).hide(500);
        clearTimeout(timer)
    });

    var timer;
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        $('#msg').show(500);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#msg').hide(500);
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zw93L/)

Update: It won't hide if you click anywhere in the page when the message is displayed, so try

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $msg = $('#msg');
    $(document).click(function () {
        if ($msg.is(':visible')) {
            $msg.hide(500);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });

    var timer;
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($msg.is(':hidden')) {
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#msg').hide(500);
            }, 3000);
        }
        $msg.toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q6bv2/)

Comment: This worked great....I needed to modify it a bit b/c the DevExpress control uses a Callback function which messed up the original code a bit, but you put me on the right track and I was able to get it working.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Can be this?

```
        $("button").click(function(e){
          $('#msg').toggle(500);
            setTimeout(function(e){
                $("#msg").fadeOut();
            }, 2000);
        });
```